# How can i add a custom xf86 mode for my Slackware system?

Tags: linux, xorg, hyper-v, slackware

I'm running `Slackware 14` in a virtual machine on `Hyper-V`.  The maximum screen resolution offered by `xf86` system is `1152x864` (reported by `xrandr`).  I'd like to add a mode for `1600x1200` resolution so I can run it full screen.
How do I go about adding this custom resolution mode?

(FYI - the kernel modules for Hyper-V are all loading - `hv_utils`, `hv_netsvc`, `hv_mouse`, `hv_storsvc`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old Slackware book used to have a section (slackware 7-8) with guidance for configuring resolutions manually. The new ["essentials"](http://slackbook.org/html/book.html#X-WINDOW-SYSTEM) book and various guides on [slackware-docs](http://docs.slackware.com)
seem to not include this, although I only had a quick look. Nonetheless, (here is what I remember from my slack days) resolutions may be configured as follows:

**$ man xorg.conf** *scroll scroll scroll*

```
SCREEN SECTION
       The  config  file  may  have  multiple Screen sections. (...) 
       Screen sections have the following format:

           Section "Screen"
               Identifier "name"
               Device     "devid"
               Monitor    "monid"
               entries
               ...
               SubSection "Display"
                  entries
                  ...
               EndSubSection
               ...
           EndSection
(...)
DISPLAY SUBSECTION
       Each Screen section may have multiple Display subsections. (...)
       Display subsections have the following format:

               SubSection "Display"
                   Depth  depth
                   entries
                   ...
               EndSubSection
       (...)
       Modes  "mode-name" ...
              This  optional  entry specifies the list of video modes to use. 
(...)
```

E.g:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen 1"
    Device         "VESA Framebuffer"
    Monitor        "My Monitor"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       8
        Modes      "1400x900" "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480"
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       16
        Modes      "1400x900" "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480"
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "1400x900" "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480"
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       32
        Modes      "1400x900" "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

This assumes that the loaded diver for the emulated graphics card ([PCI 1414:5353 VGA device](http://wiki.debian.org/WindowsServerHyperV)) in hyper-v supports the resolutions you give it. I don't think it's unreasonable to assume that it will support anything since it's done in software.

Comment: Slackware & xf86 have done such a great job with autoconfig the past few revs that I forgot how this was done.  Nice really.  I'll give this a test.

Comment: I've been unable to make this work, but I feel I'm getting close. Awarding the points